# javascript error while running application on CRM

Tags: javascript

I am working on a application and when I execute this am getting error at

```
var b=parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
```

that var a is not defined. how do I get the value of a and b. am a new learner. Thank You.

```
FieldToGet=300101; //int1
FieldToGet2=300102 //int2
FieldToSet=300103; //res


var TstFun = new function () {

this.T1=function(){
    iEventId_OnFocus=10;   
    iEventId_OnBlur=9;
    iComboType=1;


    centra.crmapi.getEditView().registerEventListener(function(obj){
        var data=obj['data'];
        var val=data[1];

        centra.crmapi.getEditView().getFieldValue(function(obj){
            var field1data=obj['data']
            var a=field1data[1];
        },FieldToGet,iComboType);

           centra.crmapi.getEditView().getFieldValue(function(obj){
            var field1data2=obj['data']
            var b=field1data2[1];
        },FieldToGet2,iComboType);

         var c=parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);

        centra.crmapi.getEditView().setFieldValue(function(obj){

        },FieldToSet,b,iComboType);

    },FieldToSet,10,iComboType);


};
};
```

Comment: (looks like you need to understand about scope (range of validity) of an identifier)

Comment: Sir,Can you please guide me what should i do to call that variable in another function.

Comment: (Generally, I prefer to be addressed as a peer (as in peer coder, not as in noble [Peerage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peerage)) - and to think of others that way.) It is considered prudent *not* to access variables from separate parts of a program: doing so creates avoidable dependencies; the mechanisms vary between languages. The accepted interface of functions/methods is *parameters* and *results* (with more than one result (even a variable number of results) coming natural in Forth/PostScript and, to some extent, Python (and probably oodles of languages unknown to me)).

Answer (score 1):

The variables `a` and `b` are both declared inside the callback functions provided to `getFieldValue`, and therefore are out of scope (i.e. invisible) to the enclosing scope (the callback to `registerEventListener`). You should hoist the declarations of `a` and `b`, and only assign to them inside the callbacks.

Also, the execution of the callbacks will be deferred, so the values assigned to `a` and `b`, even when the declarations are hoisted, will not be usable to you on subsequent lines. You need to nest the callbacks too, like so:

```
centra.crmapi.getEditView().registerEventListener(function(obj) {
    var data = obj['data'];
    var val = data[1];
    var a;
    var b;

    centra.crmapi.getEditView().getFieldValue(function(obj) {
        var field1Data = obj['data'];
        a = field1Data[1];

        centra.crmapi.getEditView().getFieldValue(function(obj) {
            var field1Data2 = obj['data']
            b = field1Data2[1];

            // This line should no longer error,
            // but `c` seems to be unused...
            var c = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);

            centra.crmapi.getEditView().setFieldValue(function(obj) {
                // I'm not sure what should go here.
                // Maybe this is where you want to use the value of `c`?
            }, FieldToSet, b, iComboType);
        }, FieldToGet2, iComboType);
    }, FieldToGet, iComboType);
}, FieldToSet, 10, iComboType);
```

All that said, I have no idea what the code is supposed to do. Your question lacks context, the naming of variables is poor, and the code style is inconsistent. Hope this helps though :)

Comment: Sir,Than Q very much. Yes am totally new to this. There is a per defined API crmapi. from that i use these functions to get a value from a screen of my application. I actually work for support. But, As i am interested in code i tried doing this and for help i posted this on web

Comment: Sir,It worked. Working fine no error. But a error in console can u please help me out.

Comment: @AbrarSami I suggest you create a new question, and make an effort to explain the problem and give a complete example.